# ORDER BY is not working properly in joins in php

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to show the last entry record  first in my datatable..so i used `ORDER BY` at the end of my query..but its not working properly.

here is my query

```
 $retval = "SELECT clientid,client_name,firstname,created_on 
            FROM `mdl_moog_clients`  
            JOIN mdl_user 
              ON mdl_moog_clients.created_by=mdl_user.id 
            where deletestatus='1' 
              and clientid!='1' 
            ORDER BY clientid DESC";
```

here clientid is the primary key

can anyone help me out..where is the mistake..

thanks in advance..

Comment: Is the `and` before `ORDER BY` a typo, or part of your actual query?

Comment: it is typo i wrote and..for separting the conditions in where i used and

Comment: What should be there instead? And can you defined "*not working properly*", what do you mean by that?

Comment: its not showing the last record first..i want to show my last entry record first

Comment: Can you show some sample data and the result you're getting?

Comment: if i remove and also its not working properly..

Comment: Why haven't you edited the question to fix the typo? Post the actual query in your code.

Comment: @Barmar can you please tell me the answer

Comment: thats my actual query..

Comment: @user200 It should work the way you wrote it, except for the typo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154963/discussion-between-user200-and-barmar).

Comment: If that's your actual query you should be getting a syntax error, not results in the wrong order.

Comment: @user200 why you put and before order by ?

Comment: @mohamadmohamad He said above that it's a typo in the question.

Comment: To other readers, the problem is actually that the result is being displayed in a datatable widget that's automatically sorting by the ID column, so the order of his query is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect to  join the `where` conditions and `order by` conditions with the word `and`.

Comment: he said this is a typo in the question.

Comment: @Barmar if it is a typo,I consider that more details should be posted ,like the actual value of the query result.

Comment: We worked it out in chat. He's displaying the result of the query using a datatables plugin that does its own sorting. The problem isn't with the query.

Comment: See the last comment I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

and misplaced before orderby

```
$retval = "SELECT clientid,client_name,firstname,created_on 
        FROM `mdl_moog_clients`  
        JOIN mdl_user 
          ON mdl_moog_clients.created_by=mdl_user.id 
        where deletestatus='1' 
          and clientid !='1'  
        ORDER BY clientid DESC";
```

Comment: He said this was a typo in the question.